# Adding alternate OpenID to Area51 private beta site does not add it to the OpenID whitelist

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, stack-exchange, beta-phase

Steps to reproduce:

1. Log in to a private beta site you've committed to with the OpenID you used on Area51.
2. On the beta site, add an alternate OpenID to your account.
3. Logout from the beta site
4. Attempt to log back in using the alternate OpenID you just added

Expected: you are logged in to your account.

Actual: you are shown a message saying that the site is in private beta, meaning that you can only login with your Area51 OpenID.

This is a small bug (although it might be a feature request) that should be easy to fix. I guess the **alternate OpenIDs just aren't being added into the OpenID whitelist**.

Comment: @Jarrod, will this also apply retroactively?

Comment: no, the alternate OpenIDs will only be added in future private beta authentications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great suggestion - this will be pushed to production this evening.